# I'm getting an error using aeproject test command with initialized project

Tags: node.js, npm, blockchain, smartcontracts, aeternity-blockchain

I installed aeproject by doing:

> $ npm install -g aeproject

Initiallized my project with

> $ aeproject init

And when I want to test it with

> $ aeproject test

I get the following error:

> (node:68448) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
> /Users/meli/MyStuff/MyAE/ae_tutorial1/node_modules/aeproject-lib/dist/aeproject-deployer.js:1
> Error: Cannot find module 'aeproject-utils' Require stack:
>
> - /Users/meli/MyStuff/MyAE/ae_tutorial1/node_modules/aeproject-lib/dist/aeproject-deployer.js
> - /Users/meli/MyStuff/MyAE/ae_tutorial1/node_modules/aeproject-lib/dist/index.js
> - /Users/meli/MyStuff/MyAE/ae_tutorial1/test/exampleTest.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aeproject/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aeproject/node_modules/mocha/index.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aeproject/aeproject-test/aeproject-test.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aeproject/aeproject-test/test.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aeproject/commands.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aeproject/aeproject-cli.js
>   at Object. (/Users/meli/MyStuff/MyAE/ae_tutorial1/node_modules/aeproject-lib/dist/aeproject-deployer.js:21:43)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:68448)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
>   rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
>   https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
>   (rejection id: 2) (node:68448) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
>   that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
>   non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this issue by doing

> $ npm install aeproject-utils prompts aeproject-logger